# String append from <select> to form new variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a combobox in HTML:

```
<select id="dimensionName"><option>/Example.html</option></select>.
```

In my JavaScript, if I have a `var URL1 = "facebook.com"`, and I want to append the selected string from the above combobox to the end of `URL1`, and set the appended string as a new variable as `NewDimensionName`, how can I do that?

I tried doing the following but to no avail:

```
var NewDimensionName = URL1.concat(document.getElementById("dimensionName").selectedItem);
```

Comment: concat is for Arrays, not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to get the text, you would have to do it like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("dimensionName");
var NewDimensionName = URL1+x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
```

This gets the options array with the selected index and returns the `text`, not the `value`.

Also note that `concat()` is used for arrays, not strings. Simply using `+` will suffice here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this one helped me finish the function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
var dimensionName= document.getElementById("dimensionName");
var dimensionText= dimensionName.options[dimensionName.selectedIndex].text;
var NewDimensionName = URL1 + dimensionText;
console.log("NewDimensionName ::" + NewDimensionName );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = document.getElementById("dimensionName").options[dimensionName.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

x = URL1 + x;

alert x;
```