# Set variables in JavaScript once function finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two functions that makes Ajax calls: getData and getMoreData. getMoreData requires a url variable that is dependent on the url variable getData. This questions continues from: [String append from <select> to form new variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001734/string-append-from-select-to-form-new-variable/21001816?noredirect=1#comment31567059_21001816).

By appending an item obtained from the  received from getData onto a base URL, I create a new variable (Let's call this NewDimensionURL) that I use for getMoreData url. However, NewDimensionURL will show error because the original list (from getData) has yet to be populated and will append nothing onto the base URL.

An idea that I have is to set NewDimensionalURL once getData finishes populating the combobox, so that getMoreData can run after.

---

### JavaScript

```
var GetDimensions = 'SomeURL1';

//--Combines URL of GetDimensionValues with #dimensionName (the select ID)
var UrlBase = "Required URL of getMoreData";
var getElement = document.getElementById("dimensionName");
var GetDimensionValues = UrlBase + getElement.options[getElement.selectedIndex].text;


function handleResults(responseObj) {
        $("#dimensionName").html(responseObj.DimensionListItem.map(function(item) {
                return $('<option>').text(item.dimensionDisplayName)[0];
    }));
}

function handleMoreResults (responseObj) {
    $("#dimensionId").html(responseObj.DimensionValueListItem.map(function(item) {
        return $('<option>').text(item.dimensionValueDisplayName)[0];
    }));
}

function getData() {
    debugger;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: GetDimensions,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
                    object = data;
        handleResults(data);
    }
});
}

function getMoreData() {
    debugger;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: GetDimensionValues,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        object = data;
        handleMoreResults (data);
    }
});
}
```

---

**Answered**

Reordered as:

```
var GetDimensionValues;


function handleResults(responseObj) {
    $("#dimensionName").html(responseObj.DimensionListItem.map(function(item) {
        return $('<option>').text(item.dimensionDisplayName)[0];
    }));
    GetDimensionValues = UrlBase + getElement.options[getElement.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Created onchange function Repopulate() for getMoreData() to parse and for handleMoreResults() to populate.

Comment: Add relevant code to this question please.

Comment: There are *so* many questions here that deal with asynchronous AJAX requests, that I think you shouldn't have trouble finding the solution.

Comment: Code has been added for context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you just do `getData(); getMoreData()` back to back? If so, then you're running getmoreData BEFORE getData has ever gotten a response back from the server.

You'll have to chain the functions, so that getMoreData only gets executed when getData gets a response. e.g.

```
$.ajax($url, {
   success: function(data) {
        getMoreData(); // call this when the original ajax call gets a response.
   }
});
```

Comment: Both getData and getMoreData outputs a json object that chains to different functions that populate different comboboxes. The result of the combobox linked to getMoreData depends on what <option> is selected from the combobox linked to getData

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to say if this is the right solution, but you should try chaining the functions:

```
$.ajax({url: yourUrl}).then(function (data) {
  // deal with the response, do another ajax call here
}).then(function () {
  // or do something here
});
```

Comment: Context to question has been added